# Add preprocessing step to Huggingface tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am training my huggingface tokenizer on my own corpora, and I want to save it with a preprocessing step. That is, if I pass some text to it, I want it to apply the preprocessing and then tokenize the text, instead of explicitly preprocessing it before that. A good example is BERTweet: https://github.com/VinAIResearch/BERTweet and their `tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/bertweet-base", normalization=True)` (here normalization=True indicates that the input will be preprocessed according to some function). I want the same to apply when I train a tokenizer with a custom preprocessing function. My code is:

```
from pathlib import Path
from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer

def preprocess(text):
    return text

paths = [str(x) for x in Path('data').glob('*.txt')]

tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()

tokenizer.train(files=paths, vocab_size=50_000, min_frequency=2,
                special_tokens=['<s>', '<pad>', '</s>', '<unk>', '<mask>'])

tokenizer.save_model('CustomBertTokenizer')
```

Now, when I load the tokenizer:

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast
sentence = 'Hey'
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('CustomBertTokenizer')
tokenizer(sentence)
```

I want `sentence` to be preprocessed with the `preprocess` function, and then tokenized. So I want to pass like an argument `preprocessing=True`, or something like that. How can I do it?